# Class type interface is not enforcing function argument types

Tags: class, interface, typescript

I have a simple class which implements an interface:

```
interface IDevice {
     electronic: boolean;
     ergonomic: boolean;
     powerOn(param1:string): boolean;
}

class ComputerMouse implements IDevice {
     electronic = true;
     ergonomic = false;

     powerOn(param1) {
         return true;
     }
}

var mouse = new ComputerMouse();
mouse.powerOn(true);
```

I can pass a boolean through to `powerOn()` when `param1` is typed as string in the interface. Shouldn't this cause a type error?

If I specify that `param1` is a boolean I rightly get a compiler error since  `ComputerMouse`'s implementation of `powerOn()` needs to match the interface.

```
class ComputerMouse implements IDevice {
 electronic = true;
 ergonomic = false;

 powerOn(param1:boolean) {
     return true;
 }
}
```

Is this intended or am I missing something?

Comment: If you change the signature of the function in the class to: `powerOn(param1:string)` you'll get an error for `mouse.powerOn(true)`, but I'm not sure why it doesn't complain without it

Comment: Yeah I am trying to figure out why it doesn't complain without it. It seems like this should not be

Comment: @NitzanTomer it seems like it's because TypeScript does not support contextual typing for implemented properties. Check out the links below

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is happening because implemented properties are not contextually typed:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373

There is a fix on the way:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118